# BLE scan getName show only specific name device

Tags: java, android

The following code looks up scan BLE devices, how to make it display only devices named "TEST". The following does not work despite the physical device called "TEST", more, in the view list I have empty fields for other devices. Thanks for help !

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        if(getActivity().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH))
            bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice>(getActivity(), 0, listItems) {
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
                BluetoothDevice device = listItems.get(position);
                if (view == null)
                    view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_item_device, parent, false);
                TextView text1 = view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = view.findViewById(R.id.text2);
                if(device.getName() == null || device.getName().isEmpty()) {
                    //text1.setText("<unnamed>");
                } else {
                    if (device.getName() == "TEST") {
                        text1.setText(device.getName());
                        text2.setText(device.getAddress());
                    }
                    return view;
                }
                return view;
            }
        };
```

Comment: In java you compare strings using the `equals` method, not using `==`.

Comment: Sorry i'm a beginner. Ok it works, how to get rid of blank entries? Thanks.

Comment: @brwtomck you can use trim() to get rid of any leading and trailing whitespace

Comment: I mean empty rows are generated in the device list

Comment: You are not setting the text of 'text1' and 'text2' if those conditions are not satisfied.

Comment: I still have empty rows.

Comment: You are inflating empty views for all bluetooth devices, even if it is not matching TEST.

Comment: how not to do it? when does a function need to return view?